# Feature spec pass locally but fail on Circle CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, circleci

I have feature specs for my ActiveAdmin view. It works on my local machine. But when ran in CircleCi it fails with

```
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
```

#### spec

```
it 'uses the update_at date when prepaid_invoice' do
  travel_to(5.days.ago) { create_prepayment }

  travel_to(3.days.ago) do
    visit '/admin/payments'

    expect(page).not_to have_css('.col.col-created > div')
    amount = all('.col-amount').last
    expect(amount.text).to eq('$1,000.00') # failing here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`all` behaves different depending on whether you're on a current release of Capybara or the older 2.x version.  In current versions `all` will wait for up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for any matching elements to appear and if none do it will return an empty array (actually Array like Result object, but close enough). In 2.x `all` (by default) did no waiting for matching elements, it would just return the empty array if no elements matched.  Either way - you're not finding any matching elements, and then calling `last` on an empty array - giving you `nil`.

There are a couple of ways around this.  You could tell `all` that you expect at least one matching element ( which will then force waiting for matching elements Capybara 2.x )

```
amount = all('.col-amount', minimum: 1).last
```

or depending on exactly what you're checking you could just combine it into one

```
expect(page).to have_css('.col-amount', exact_text:'$1,000.00')
```

which gets away from calling methods on Capybara elements and using the generic RSpec matchers on them (which is something you don't want to do, for test stability reasons, unless you have no other options). Those two solution don't test exactly the same thing, but may test enough for what you want. Depending on exactly how your HTML is structured there may be more efficient solutions too.

If you're already using a recent version of Capybara then your error would indicate that what you expect to be on the page isn't (maybe you're on an error page, etc) or you don't have `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set high enough for the system you're testing on.

Comment: I updated to use `expect(page).to have_css('.col-amount', exact_text: '$1,000.00')` which also passes locally. But it fails on CircleCi as well.

Comment: @AntarrByrd Which version of Capybara are you using? Also - what is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: The error is `Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('.col-amount', exact_text: '$1,000.00')
       expected to find css ".col-amount" but there were no matches
` Using     `capybara (3.16.1)` according to Gemfile.lock

Comment: @AntarrByrd Ok - then as stated at the end of my answer - you're not on the page you think you are or the content isn't what you expect - Use `page.save_screenshot` or output `page.html` to see what the actual page is.  The other option is try increasing `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` (experiment with 20 or so) to see if it's just the CircleCI systems being slow.